# Clearing eclipse workspace using command arguments

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

How to clear workspace using command arguments.
I want to do same behavior as in eclipse launch or debug configuration where checking clear clears the workspace using command arguments.
I tried using -clean and -clearws=true as program argument but no success.

Comment: I don't think there is a command argument to do this.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this.

Comment: If  you are running an Eclipse RCP you could probably clear the workspace folder in the `IApplication` class before starting the RCP.

Comment: Thanks, i am proceeding with deleting things from the workspace

Comment: Check if the solution in [this post on the Eclipse Forums](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=207413&goto=664149&#msg_664149) matches your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Use -clearPersistedState as command line argument to clear the eclipse workspace.

Comment: you can comment on this and not answer.